# Problems loading images async in mono for android

Tags: android, asynchronous, mono, xamarin.android

I am starting to develop a new App in mono for Android that requires me to load a lot of images from a remote server. In order to do this I programmed a view that I can plug in a layout and it loads the images in the background. This works very nice until I use it in an Adapter for ListView, which is where I was mainly planning to use it. The application loads some images and not others and it loads them in the wrong places. As soon as you scroll the list it starts loading the images correctly, but the first images that are displayed are incomplete and wrong. I have tried different strategies to run the background process (asynctask, threadpools, etc.) and all have the same problem. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Util;
using System.Net;
using Android.Graphics;
using ListViewExample;
using System.Threading;

namespace klvpn.components
{
    public class WebImageView : RelativeLayout
    {
        ImageView theImage;
        TextView waitingTxt;
        Activity context;
        Uri imageUri;
        WebClient wc;

        public WebImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
            base(context, attrs)
        {
            this.context = context as Activity;

            this.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
            this.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);
            waitingTxt = new TextView(context);
            waitingTxt.SetText("...", TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            AddView(waitingTxt, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WrapContent, LayoutParams.WrapContent));

        }

        public void SetImageSize(int width, int height)
        {
            LayoutParameters.Width = width;
            LayoutParameters.Height = height;
        }

        public void SetImageUriStr(string uriStr)
        {
            imageUri = new Uri(uriStr);

            if (theImage == null)
            {
                theImage = new ImageView(context);
                AddView(theImage, 0);
            }
            wc = new WebClient();
            wc.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadDataCompleted);
            wc.DownloadDataAsync(imageUri);
        }

        void wc_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                context.RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {               
                    theImage.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.noImage_x);                  
                    string error = "URI:" + imageUri.OriginalString + "\n" + e.Error.Message;
                    Log.Error("WebImageView", error);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(e.Result, 0, e.Result.Length);
                context.RunOnUiThread(() =>
                {
                    theImage.SetImageBitmap(bmp);
                });
            }
            wc = null;
        }

        protected override void OnDetachedFromWindow()
        {
            base.OnDetachedFromWindow();
            if (wc != null)
            {
                wc.CancelAsync();
            }

        }


    }
}
```

and the GetView method of the adapter looks like this:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = this.Episodes[position];
            var view = convertView;
            if (convertView == null || !(convertView is LinearLayout))
            {
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.EpisodeItem, parent, false);
            }

            var imageItem = view.FindViewById<WebImageView>(Resource.Id.imageItem);
            var textTop = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textTop);
            var textBottom = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textBottom);

            //imageItem.SetImageResource(item.Image);
            imageItem.SetImageSize(100, 36);
            imageItem.SetImageUriStr(item.ImageUri);
            textTop.SetText(item.Name, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            textBottom.SetText(item.Description, TextView.BufferType.Normal);

            return view;

        }
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem? I used this strategy with MonoTouch and is very nice since the image download is encapsulated and the user doesn't have to wait until everything loads before they can see something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the library : http://code.google.com/p/android-query/
it's really simple and it's fast to integrate.

Comment: Thanks Anis, the library looks great. Unfortunately binding a Java library to C# is still not that easy. It would be great if the guys at Xamarin would give it a go though, since it looks really useful.

Comment: It is quite a lot easier than it used to be, have you taken a look at [this](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/Java_Integration_Overview/Binding_a_Java_Library_(.jar))